# ipsec encryption support in linux: SADB_EALG_NONE vs SADB_EALG_NULL

Tags: c, linux, ipsec

In `linux/pfkeyv2.h` I can see following values:

```
#define SADB_EALG_NONE          0
...
#define SADB_EALG_NULL          11
```

Anyone can explain what is the difference between those values and how specifying those values in `sadb_sa.sadb_sa_encrypt` would affect ipsec encryption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SADB_EALG_NONE` is used to indicate that no encryption applies for an SA, while `SADB_EALG_NULL` signifies the NULL encryption algorithm as specified in [RFC 2410](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2410). As stated in [RFC 2367, section 3.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2367#section-3.5) the former must only be used if no encryption can apply for an SA (e.g. for AH), the latter may be used for ESP SAs and can be negotiated via IKE.

Comment: what would be null encryption for windows then? as per [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366296(v=vs.85).aspx)  it does not provide null cipher